# Fitting a UIImage to the center of screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a viewcontroller,in which a UIImageview is subviewed. The UIImages come in different size and orientations. But i wanna be able to fit them in the middle of the screen.
I tried to define a frame for the UIImageview but i cant get the 4 parameters of the CGRectMake right.

Comment: Just set the view's center to the container's center. And there is no 'subviewing' btw.

Comment: @Jenox Since Im creating the UIImageview programmatically i need to subview it to the view.

Comment: That just sounds wrong. You need to add it as a subview to a container view.

Comment: I dunno dude its working for me this way. i use [self.view addsubview:myImageView]

Comment: I'm not saying that what you are doing is wrong I'm just saying the way you call it is wrong.

Comment: Ok then how should i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIImage *backgroundLogoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"center_logo.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundLogoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
backgroundLogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (backgroundLogoImage.size.width / 2), (self.view.frame.size.height / 2) - (backgroundLogoImage.size.height / 2), backgroundLogoImage.size.width, backgroundLogoImage.size.height);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a property "center": you can do something like this:

```
UIImageView * img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
img.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: Useful - But that works for UIImageView - not UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

Set your image View to be the size you want all the images to be. Sound to me like you want it to be full device screen.

```
  imageView.frame = self.view.frame; // or what ever;
  // if its a custom size,set size and then call imageView.center = self.view.center;
```

Add the image to the imageView but set content mode to allow scaling.

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"];
 image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 image.clipsToBounds = YES;
 imageView.image = image;
```

This should result in the image either scaling down or up to fit the imageView's frame.

Comment: There is no contentMode or clipsToBound attributes in UIImage type. It's in the UIImageView